typescript transpilation error not verbose
I am having troubles with transpiling typescript. The issue is that error message is not descriptive. In the example below, no line number is listed and no info on the problematic reserved word. How should I configure tsconfig.json so that transpilation error messages are more verbose and at least include line number of the code that failed to compile?
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:155:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:30)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21)

when run
/path/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node --require ts-node/register --loader=ts-node/esm --trace-warnings /path/src/home-client.ts

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "es2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "decorators",
      "dom",
      "es2021"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/extensions"
  ],
  "ts-node": {
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "esm": true,
  }
}

Exmaple code to trigger the above listed error:
let arr = [1,2,3];
async function doIt(){return true;}
arr.filter(()=>{return await doIt()}); //nonsense to use await in filter, but it server demonstration purpose

Run with:     /path/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node --require ts-node/register --loader=ts-node/esm --trace-warnings /path/demo.ts

Hi !
Can you show a minimal reproducible example of the code ?
I try to reproduce with the same tsconfig using const delete = 10; but i got a really descriptive error.

Hi @Xapadoan.  I've added an example. It seems await in non async function is triggering the issue. The error example given is detected by IDE, which is not the always the case.
